# Mozilla декодирует url в адресной строке

Tags: javascript, http, url, get, firefox

Mozilla декодирует закодированный url в адресной строке. Из-за чего получаю bad request, т.к. бек не понимает некоторые спец. символы.
В других браузерах такой проблемы нет. При всем этом, если вбить в адресную строку закодированный url, Mozilla его декодирует.
Что можно сделать с этим?
Пример:

Mozilla:

```
ge[dateTime]=2019-06-03&le[dateTime]=2019-06-03
```

Chromium:

```
ge%5BdateTime%5D=2019-06-03&le%5BdateTime%5D=2019-06-03
```

Пример кода:

```
<a class="navbar-item" href="custom-url?ge%5BdateTime%5D={{dateString}}&le%5BdateTime%5D={{dateString}}">Ссылка</a>
```

Comment: Откуда берется URL? Может проблема с точностью до наоборот? Chromium **перекодирует** URL, а Mozilla отправляет как есть?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, как я уже писал выше, такое происходит даже при вставке url хардом в адресную строку.
Используется роутинг jquery, а так же в некоторых местах url'ы забиты в html страницах.

Comment: Код не вставляет URL в адресную строку. Давайте реальный код

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, приложил "код" выше.
Переход по ссылке происходит напрямую. Минуя js.
И этот код тоже декодируется.

Comment: Т.е. строку обрабатывет еще какой-то шаблонизатор? Покажите результирующее содержание html

Comment: Как минимум, здесь `&le` ошибка. Нужно писать `&amp;le`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, по вашему, из-за неправильного параметра, выполняется правильный запрос, и при этом декодируется url?

Comment: Я прошу привести конечный html без ошибок.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, это корректный url, который работает везде, кроме mozilla и если вы запихнете параметры в url декодер, то получите корректный результат.

ge[dateTime]={{dateString}}&le[dateTime]={{dateString}}"

И кодировать & на сколько мне известно тут не нужно. {{dateString}} подставляется mustache по ходу рендеринга страницы.

Повторюсь, работает во всех браузерах, кроме mozilla, даже в IE9 проблем нет.